# Footer floating to the bottom, good. But what about columns

Tags: html, css, css-float, footer

I have code as such:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left-column">Floating left.</div>
    <div id="right-column">Floating right.</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">BlahBlah</div>
```

Container allows me to push the footer to the bottom of the page, but if I want the left and right column to span the height touching the footer, how can this be done?

Comment: Once you've accepted some answers (the tick mark on your previously asked questions) try adding your code to http://jsfiddle.net/ for us to fiddle with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set your page's html and body elements to 100% height. Then your columns will fill the page height if you also set them to 100%.

The full CSS (including your own) is as follows. Background colour is used to illustrate layout.

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
}

#container {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
}

#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #FC0;
}

#left-column {
    background-color: #666;
    width :50%;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}

#right-column {
    background-color: #CCC;
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
}
```

By setting padding to zero on the body you remove a horizontal scroll when the page is empty. Also be aware that by using absolute positioning for your footer it will overlap the content of the content columns.

Here is a fiddle illustrating the layout - http://jsfiddle.net/BuKcH/